# How to get xml result param value for jsp

Tags: jsp, struts2

I want to put a result param named `contents` from action XML to `<s:include>` tag `value` attribute to add other JSP file dynamically. This is what inside the JSP page :

```
<s:include value="%{#parameters['contents']}"/>
```

And this is the action result inside xml

```xml
<action name="list" class="control.action.hrp.AllowanceList">
    <result name="success" type="dispatcher">
        <param name="location">/WEB-INF/main/template/body.jsp</param>
        <param name="contents">/WEB-INF/main/content/Content.jsp</param>
    </result>
    <result name="error">/index.jsp</result>
</action>
```

The body.jsp doesn't load "Content.jsp"
Is there any way to put the value of `contents` param to JSP ?

Thanks for any help that you suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to create a `contents` variable in your `control.action.hrp.AllowanceList` action with getter/setter.

The `param` tag in struts.xml should be directly inside `action` tag not a `result` tag.

```xml
<action name="list" class="control.action.hrp.AllowanceList">
    <param name="contents">/WEB-INF/main/content/Content.jsp</param>

    <result name="success" type="dispatcher">/WEB-INF/main/template/body.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">/index.jsp</result>
</action>
```

And in JSP just use `contents` variable:

```
<s:include value="%{contents}"/>
```

Comment: thanks, it works altought it needs more works than I think